# Drools + Hibernate how to write rules in object terms

Tags: hibernate, drools

Hi I have this drl rule using hibernate Session :-

```
 rule 
    email optout action 1" salience 200
      when
       $ot: OTOptPref(dntEmail == true, srcSystem=="CIS")
       $st: STOptPref() from hibernateSession.createQuery("from STOptPref p where p.emailId=:emailId ").setString("emailId",$ot.emailId).list()
       then
        $ot.setLogMessage("Data originated from CIS,no changes applied");
        System.out.println(" 1 The game "+$ot.getLogMessage());
      end
```

need help on how to write it in object terms only avoiding query ?? trying something like this doesnt work :

```
 rule "email optout action 1" salience 200
      when
       $ot: OTOptPref()
       $st: STOptPref( $ot.isDntEmail() == true,emailId == $ot.getEmailId())    
      then
         $ot.setLogMessage("Data originated from CIS,no changes applied");
         System.out.println(" 1 The game "+$ot.getLogMessage());
      end
```